# Send request params through JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc

I m still new with both Angular and Spring MVC. I'm looking forward for your help.

This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/PostFormData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User PostService(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
        return user;
    }
```

My Js file (I'm actually working  with AngularJS):

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return $.param(data);
    }
});
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
         templateUrl: 'index.html'
        }).when('/profile',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/profile.html'
    });
 });
    app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [];
        $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
        $scope.submit = function() {
                var formData = {
                    "firstName" : $scope.firstName,
                    "lastName" : $scope.lastName,
                    "login" : $scope.login,
                    "password":$scope.password,
                    "role" :$scope.role
            };
            var response = $http.post('PostFormData',formData);
            response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.list.push(data);
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: You could try ```$http.post('PostFormData', null, formData)```. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post . ParamsObject is the 3rd argument for POST.

Comment: I've tryed but still not working :/